# Rosemary, Heaven restores you in life

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> It spent a life span with no cellmate
>   The long way back
>   saying me why can't we look the other way?
>   You're weightless, semi-erotic
>   You need someone to take you there
>   saying me why can't we look the other way?
>   Why can't we just play the other game?
>
> 21, 48, 101, 23, 48, 209, 237, 7

Decode the sequence to find the answer

Hint 1:

> Claymation of nightmares